# How can i automatically calculate values provided in 10 min time steps to average values in 1 h time steps?

Tags: r, time-series, data.table, average, lubridate

My dataframe consists of data in 10 min time steps for a period of 4 years. My other data is provided in 1 hour time steps. So i need to convert the 10 min data to 1 hour average values to combine it with my other data.

here is a dput of the first 25 rows of my data:

```
    structure(list(...1 = structure(c(1420070400, 1420071000, 1420071600, 
1420072200, 1420072800, 1420073400, 1420074000, 1420074600, 1420075200, 
1420075800, 1420076400, 1420077000, 1420077600, 1420078200, 1420078800, 
1420079400, 1420080000, 1420080600, 1420081200, 1420081800, 1420082400, 
1420083000, 1420083600, 1420084200, 1420084800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Dd1_1...2 = c(28.43869, 28.52743, 28.52743, 28.52743, 
28.57417, 28.57417, 28.57417, 28.67358, 28.67358, 28.67358, 28.62449, 
28.62449, 28.62449, 28.74658, 28.74658, 28.74658, 29.01779, 29.01779, 
29.01779, 28.84344, 28.84344, 28.84344, 28.7406, 28.7406, 28.7406
), Dd1_3...3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    Dd1_5...4 = c(30.58685, 31.82736, 31.82736, 31.82736, 29.77018, 
    29.77018, 29.77018, 29.91568, 29.91568, 29.91568, 29.69438, 
    29.69438, 29.69438, 30.45421, 30.45421, 30.45421, 30.06922, 
    30.06922, 30.06922, 30.15059, 30.15059, 30.15059, 30.41779, 
    30.41779, 30.41779), Dd1_1...5 = c(28.24055, 28.273, 28.273, 
    28.273, 28.26098, 28.26098, 28.26098, 28.29342, 28.29342, 
    28.29342, 28.24657, 28.24657, 28.24657, 28.34867, 28.34867, 
    28.34867, 28.30063, 28.30063, 28.30063, 28.17804, 28.17804, 
    28.17804, 28.30423, 28.30423, 28.30423), Dd1_3...6 = c(25.25317, 
    25.53266, 25.53266, 25.53266, 25.50203, 25.50203, 25.50203, 
    25.49713, 25.49713, 25.49713, 25.30346, 25.30346, 25.30346, 
    25.36477, 25.36477, 25.36477, 25.46037, 25.46037, 25.46037, 
    25.26299, 25.26299, 25.26299, 25.37948, 25.37948, 25.37948
    ), Dd1_5...7 = c(27.75881, 27.92162, 27.92162, 27.92162, 
    28.65922, 28.65922, 28.65922, 26.65354, 26.65354, 26.65354, 
    27.10426, 27.10426, 27.10426, 28.48427, 28.48427, 28.48427, 
    26.80799, 26.80799, 26.80799, 27.33572, 27.33572, 27.33572, 
    27.20004, 27.20004, 27.20004), Dd1_1...8 = c(28.23214, 28.81236, 
    28.81236, 28.81236, 28.81834, 28.81834, 28.81834, 28.29463, 
    28.29463, 28.29463, 28.35347, 28.35347, 28.35347, 28.19247, 
    28.19247, 28.19247, 28.30664, 28.30664, 28.30664, 28.24776, 
    28.24776, 28.24776, 28.2694, 28.2694, 28.2694), Dd1_3...9 = c(29.27281, 
    29.31683, 29.31683, 29.31683, 29.75479, 29.75479, 29.75479, 
    29.69912, 29.69912, 29.69912, 29.97595, 29.97595, 29.97595, 
    29.19542, 29.19542, 29.19542, 29.19661, 29.19661, 29.19661, 
    29.90859, 29.90859, 29.90859, 29.57938, 29.57938, 29.57938
    ), Dd1_5...10 = c(28.02402, 28.33666, 28.33666, 28.33666, 
    28.48547, 28.48547, 28.48547, 27.7383, 27.7383, 27.7383, 
    NA, NA, NA, 27.69604, 27.69604, 27.69604, 28.44109, 28.44109, 
    28.44109, 28.77409, 28.77409, 28.77409, 27.93246, 27.93246, 
    27.93246), Dd1_1...23 = c(-11.97827, -11.99765, -11.96991, 
    -12.04475, -12.07237, -12.12492, -12.1001, -12.15241, -12.1885, 
    -12.19432, -12.25232, -12.31324, -12.28841, -12.34945, -12.38554, 
    -12.36858, -12.40782, -12.44645, -12.46292, -12.50446, -12.54636, 
    -12.54369, -12.58269, -12.62713, -12.61042), Dd1_3...24 = c(-9.715732, 
    -9.693569, -9.621514, -9.632534, -9.57162, -9.563144, -9.48576, 
    -9.479946, -9.435623, -9.363811, -9.3913, -9.360904, -9.29454, 
    -9.277949, -9.261358, -9.183611, -9.18676, -9.150551, -9.08673, 
    -9.095086, -9.056576, -8.96793, -8.888002, -8.863055, -8.74692
    ), Dd1_5...25 = c(-9.247674, -9.076073, -8.876861, -8.791121, 
    -8.69424, -8.583553, -8.395483, -8.317978, -8.232359, -8.171687, 
    -8.105203, -8.091396, -7.887099, -7.862273, -7.765512, -7.594275, 
    -7.555886, -7.511563, -7.442535, -7.337661, -7.238479, -7.064819, 
    -6.924341, -6.858099, -6.615532)), row.names = c(NA, -25L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

i hope there is an easy sulution to convert the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(`...1` = trunc(`...1`, "hour")) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), mean), .groups = "drop")
# # A tibble: 5 x 13
#   ...1                Dd1_1...2 Dd1_3...3 Dd1_5...4 Dd1_1...5 Dd1_3...6 Dd1_5...7 Dd1_1...8 Dd1_3...9 Dd1_5...10 Dd1_1...23 Dd1_3...24 Dd1_5...25
#   <dttm>                  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 2015-01-01 00:00:00      28.5        NA      30.9      28.3      25.5      28.1      28.7      29.5       28.3      -12.0      -9.63      -8.88
# 2 2015-01-01 01:00:00      28.6        NA      29.8      28.3      25.4      27.1      28.4      29.8       NA        -12.2      -9.42      -8.22
# 3 2015-01-01 02:00:00      28.8        NA      30.2      28.3      25.4      27.7      28.3      29.3       NA        -12.4      -9.23      -7.70
# 4 2015-01-01 03:00:00      28.8        NA      30.2      28.2      25.3      27.2      28.3      29.7       28.4      -12.5      -8.99      -7.14
# 5 2015-01-01 04:00:00      28.7        NA      30.4      28.3      25.4      27.2      28.3      29.6       27.9      -12.6      -8.75      -6.62
```

If you need the `Dd1_t...10` values of `NA` to be averaged removing the `NA`s, then simply

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(`...1` = trunc(`...1`, "hour")) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE)), groups = "drop")
# # A tibble: 5 x 14
#   ...1                Dd1_1...2 Dd1_3...3 Dd1_5...4 Dd1_1...5 Dd1_3...6 Dd1_5...7 Dd1_1...8 Dd1_3...9 Dd1_5...10 Dd1_1...23 Dd1_3...24 Dd1_5...25 groups
#   <dttm>                  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <chr> 
# 1 2015-01-01 00:00:00      28.5       NaN      30.9      28.3      25.5      28.1      28.7      29.5       28.3      -12.0      -9.63      -8.88 drop  
# 2 2015-01-01 01:00:00      28.6       NaN      29.8      28.3      25.4      27.1      28.4      29.8       27.9      -12.2      -9.42      -8.22 drop  
# 3 2015-01-01 02:00:00      28.8       NaN      30.2      28.3      25.4      27.7      28.3      29.3       28.0      -12.4      -9.23      -7.70 drop  
# 4 2015-01-01 03:00:00      28.8       NaN      30.2      28.2      25.3      27.2      28.3      29.7       28.4      -12.5      -8.99      -7.14 drop  
# 5 2015-01-01 04:00:00      28.7       NaN      30.4      28.3      25.4      27.2      28.3      29.6       27.9      -12.6      -8.75      -6.62 drop
```

Though now you have a `NaN` problem :-)

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dat)
DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = list(`...1`=as.POSIXct(trunc(`...1`, "hour")))]
```

Similarly, for the `NA`s:

```r
DT[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE), by = list(`...1`=as.POSIXct(trunc(`...1`, "hour")))]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. While looking at my data i saw that NA values set the value for the complete hour to NA as well. Is there a way to exclude the NA values in this code?

Comment: Do you mean `mean(., na.rm=TRUE)`?

Comment: exactly. But if i put this to the code like:
Dedelow_Sensor<-Dedelow_Sensor %>%
  group_by(`...1` = trunc(`...1`, "hour")) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), mean(na.rm=TRUE)))
i get an error

Comment: See my edit. Long story short: you can't provide an arbitrary expression like that without telling `dplyr` (`rlang`, really) what you want to do with it. The `~` notation is a pseudo-function, and the `.` is replaced with the actual "data" for each column.

Comment: For example, `across(everything(), mean)` is perfectly equivalent to `across(everything(), ~ mean(.))`. The latter syntax allows you to add arguments to the function call, as I did by adding `na.rm=TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This edit works for me and the NaN is no problem. Like this, i can combine my dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Revised answer :

```
df["average"] = df["values"].rolling(6).mean()
```

Now the average column will have the value you wanted and can be picked out to a new dataframe.

Old Answer :
If the first row is for 0th hour, 0th min and 0th seconds then the 6th record would be 1st hour, 0th min and 0th seconds. And the 12th record will be 2nd hour, 0th min and 0th seconds

So we are looking at picking the 0th, 6th, 12th records and so on...

If you think this helps, then my code could be like

```
dfHour = df[df.index % 6 == 0]
```

The above will provide you those rows that have indexes that are multiples of 6.

Comment: The problem is that i can not just pick every sixth row to combine it with my other data. I have to use average values and in best case create a dataframe which is only 1/6 of the length of the original one.

Comment: In which case, you can do a nested loop of 6 rows and then apply sum() / 6, then move to index 6 for the  next set of 6 records ?

Comment: Did I miss a discussion about bringing python/pandas into the fold?

Comment: Or, more excitedly, is there an R package that more closely mimics pandas and its dot-chaining? :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your table is called. So I called it `dat`.

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
dat %>% 
  mutate(hour = floor_date(x = ...1, unit = 'hour')) %>% 
  group_by(hour) %>% 
  select(-...1) %>% 
  summarise_all(mean)
```

Mutate uses `floor_date` from the lubridate package to extract the hour truncated date of the date and put it in a column called 'hour'. Then we group by that hour column and select out (with the negative symbol) the date field. Finally we summarise all the other columns by `mean`